# Nvidia - The EDID for CNDLCD (DFP-1) contradicts itself

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg

I keep getting the following error on my xorg.log file which causes my TV monitor to not be able to get 1920x1080 and other smaller resolutions:

```
[    26.967] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): The EDID for CNDLCD (DFP-1) contradicts itself: mode "720x576"
[    26.967] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     is specified in the EDID; however, the EDID's valid
[    26.967] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     HorizSync range (30.000-95.000 kHz) would exclude this
[    26.967] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     mode's HorizSync (15.6 kHz); ignoring HorizSync check for
[    26.967] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     mode "720x576".
[    26.967] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): The EDID for CNDLCD (DFP-1) contradicts itself: mode "720x576"
[    26.967] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     is specified in the EDID; however, the EDID's valid
[    26.967] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     VertRefresh range (60.000-75.000 Hz) would exclude this
[    26.967] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     mode's VertRefresh (50.0 Hz); ignoring VertRefresh check
[    26.967] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     for mode "720x576".
[    26.967] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): The EDID for CNDLCD (DFP-1) contradicts itself: mode
[    26.967] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     "1920x1080" is specified in the EDID; however, the EDID's
[    26.967] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     valid VertRefresh range (60.000-75.000 Hz) would exclude
[    26.967] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     this mode's VertRefresh (50.0 Hz); ignoring VertRefresh
[    26.967] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     check for mode "1920x1080".
```

How can I solve this. I have the proprietary drivers from the Nvidia PPA right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the EDID information being returned by your TV monitor is invalid. You should check the resolutions listed in its manual.

You should be able to define modes as listed in your monitor's manual. Put these in an /etc/X11/xorg.conf file and also add `Option "UseEDID" "False"`

A vertical refresh rate of 50Hz does seem slow; I'd particularly double check the bit frequency being specified by the monitor's EDID.

Comment: 50Hz is the standard PAL refresh rate. It is also a valid computer LCD refresh rate, and is often used for "power saving" (though I think that's dubious).

Comment: There are also some laptops LCD that support 40Hz besides 60Hz.